# Is ANSI standard and portable for terminals?

Tags: c, terminal

I have a program in C where I want to draw colors and move cursors, etc. in the terminal. Currently, I am just using ANSI escape codes to do this. Is ANSI the most modern and most popular/used standard? Is it portable? Will more or fewer terminals support ANSI in the future?

Comment: if a terminal supports colorized text then yes, it's a good bet it does so via ascii escape codes.

Comment: For better portability, you might want to use a library like ncurses to handle the platform-specific parts.

Comment: @bolov Er, that’s not quite correct. There are bazillions of _legacy_ terminals which do not support so-called ANSI escape codes. Modern terminal emulators, however, tend toward a common set.

Comment: Make sure to test on Windows. I don't know the current state, but they used to not work there.

Answer (score 2):

Modern terminal emulators (just about anything normal people will encounter these days) all tend to use stuff you can find documented in two places:

[Microsoft’s “Console Virtual Terminal Sequences”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

[Thomas Dickey’s “XTerm Control Sequences”](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

It doesn’t get more authoritative than that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that ANSI is going to be pretty reliably portable for some time to come.

However, it's possibly more productive and more protected from changes in underlying standards (e.g. a resurgence of PC3270) to use a library. There's an enormous list of them [here](https://github.com/rothgar/awesome-tuis), under the **Libraries** section. `Ncurses` seems to be something of a staple, and `notcurses` has a lot of merit too.